# Can't Hide a QtAndroid Splashscreen with QtAndroid::hideSplashScreen();

Tags: android, c++, qt, qml, qtandroidextras

I am currently developing a Qt C++/QML app for android and I've come across an issue. By following the steps in this guide: [HERE](https://medium.com/@benlaud/complete-guide-to-make-a-splash-screen-for-your-qml-android-application-567ca3bc70af).

This produces a very clean and functional SplashScreen (natively I assume). However, It instructs me to use `QtAndroid::hideSplashScreen();` to hide the splashscreen when all elements are loaded. This method just leaves me with a blank screen as shown below:

[image]

[image]

There are no error messages shown regarding the success/failure to display/hide this element. After "hiding" it, there is no view display (my view should be shown at this time.)

My method for hiding the splashscreen is as follows:

```
using namespace Esri::ArcGISRuntime;

CanfieldFairApp::CanfieldFairApp(QObject* parent /* = nullptr */):
    QObject(parent),
    m_map(new Map(Basemap::streetsNightVector(this), this))
{
    connect(m_mapView, SIGNAL(navigatingChangedEvent()), this, SLOT(navigatingChangedEvent()));

    connect(m_map, &Esri::ArcGISRuntime::Map::loadStatusChanged, this, [](Esri::ArcGISRuntime::LoadStatus loadStatus)
    {
        if (loadStatus == LoadStatus::Loaded)
        {
            QtAndroid::hideSplashScreen();
            qDebug() << "Map Loaded!";
        }
    });
}
```

As a result I do see "Map Loaded!" Called, but nothing appears.

Keep in mind, without a splashscreen, the Main View displays perfectly fine.

AppTheme.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">#ffffff</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Splash.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
        </shape>
    </item>    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/app"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

AndroidManifest.xml sections:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtApplication" android:label="Canfield Fair App" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <activity android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|mcc|mnc|density" android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity" android:label="Canfield Fair App" android:screenOrientation="unspecified" android:launchMode="singleTop">
```

---

```
<meta-data android:name="android.app.splash_screen_drawable" android:resource="@drawable/splash"/>
<meta-data android:name="android.app.splash_screen_sticky" android:value="true"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried it without `splash_screen_sticky`? Generally speaking, to debug this I would install Android Studio, launch the app normally and then attach the debugger and put some breakpoints on hideSplashScreen in this code: https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/android/jar/src/org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtActivityDelegate.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix seems to be removing `<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>` from AppTheme.xml.

Tested on Qt 5.14.2 / Android.